# Order of Operations in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm a new Fortran 90 user and have a relatively simple question. Within a subroutine I'm running the following code:

```
y = (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *(1-yin)*(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*yin    *(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*yin    *zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *(1-yin)*zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *yin    *(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *yin    *zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *(1-yin)*(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*yin    *(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*zin    *qin     &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*(1-xin)*yin    *zin    *qin     &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *(1-yin)*zin    *qin     &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *yin    *(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (1-crra)*(f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra))*xin    *yin    *zin    *qin
```

When I replace that chunk of code with the following code I get around a 2X speed-up:

```
y = (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *(1-yin)*(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*yin    *(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*yin    *zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *(1-yin)*zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *yin    *(1-zin)*(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)  ))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *yin    *zin    *(1-qin) &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *(1-yin)*(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*yin    *(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*(1-yin)*zin    *qin     &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)  , llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*(1-xin)*yin    *zin    *qin     &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)  , llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *(1-yin)*zin    *qin     &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)  , llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *yin    *(1-zin)*qin     &
  + (((1-crra)*f(llc(1)+1, llc(2)+1, llc(3)+1, llc(4)+1))**(1/(1-crra)))*xin    *yin    *zin    *qin
```

Why am I getting a speed-up here? Is there a general Fortran lesson here or is this specific to my application?

Comment: Are you using -O3 to optimize the code? Sometimes speed differences go away when optimization is turned on. A side point is that unless the code is machine-generated, I would worry about errors in the expressions, since they are complicated.

Comment: Not very likely to be general. Please show us how exactly you compile the code 1. the compile version, 2. the compiler flags. To say anything real, we would need some complete code that can be tested. We do not even know what your symbols are.

Comment: My first concern would be to turn either of the above into something readable and maintainable, well before I started caring about too much about speed; such code would probably help the optimiser as a side effect. Note also I doubt you are using the very old Fortran 90 - much more likely something appreciably more modern that that - 2003 or 2008 most likely.

Comment: I think your two snippets do different things. I think the first one is `a*(f^b)` and the second one is `(a*f)^b`, where in both cases `a=(1-crra)` and `b=1/(1-crra)`. These are not the same.

Comment: @veryreverie Great example of why a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is essential!

Comment: Thanks all for the comments! I will work on producing an example (this is machine-generated from some confidential code), but my question was whether there was a more general point about Fortran I was missing. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment about speed without knowing more about your variables and the function `f`. But can I recommend generating `y` algorithmically rather than with a single huge expression?

Something like

```
! I'm guessing at the types of these.
integer :: arguments(2,4) 
integer :: factors(2,4)

arguments(1,:) = llc
arguments(2,:) = llc+1

factors(1,:) = 1-[xin, yin, zin, quin]
factors(2,:) = [xin, yin, zin, quin]

! Initialise `y` to `0`.
y = 0

! Loop over four indices, one each for x, y, z and q.
do i=1,2
  do j=1,2
    do k=1,2
      do l=1,2
        ! Calculate the contribution to `y`.
        y = y &
          + f(arguments(i,1), arguments(j,2), arguments(k,3), arguments(l,4)) &
          ** (1/(1-crra)) &
          * factors(i,1)*factors(j,2)*factors(k,3)*factors(l,4)
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
enddo

! Multiply `y` by `(1-crra)`.
y = y*(1-crra)
```

This might run slower than your code, but with a bit of refactoring it should be possible to make it faster.

The advantages of this kind of approach are that it's much more readable and maintainable.